# Getting Buffer is not defined when using gray-matter in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

Trying to use [`gray-matter`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gray-matter) in Angular 9 and getting the following error:

```
ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined
    at Object.push../node_modules/gray-matter/lib/utils.js.exports.toBuffer (utils.js:32)
    at push../node_modules/gray-matter/lib/to-file.js.module.exports (to-file.js:28)
    at matter (index.js:34)
    at initializeTopic (utilities.ts:97)
    at content.service.ts:320
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:364)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:41275)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:363)
    at Zone.run (zone-evergreen.js:123)
    at zone-evergreen.js:857
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Found a related question that said that adding this to polyfills.js resolves it and it does:

```
(window as any).global = window;
global.Buffer = global.Buffer || require('buffer').Buffer;
(window as any).process = {
  version: ''
};
```